# How to detect if a site is Mobile-Friendly (mobile and responsive without USER AGENT)

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, responsiveness

I need to find a method and check if a site is mobile and reponsive
Without USER agnet
I see that sites (e.g [google checker](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/)) idetify it as reponsive but I dont know why.

Comment: So you want to pre-check if a site is mobile friendly? This question is not clear. How are you viewing the site?

Comment: I have a site that that seems to be mobile friendly(behave as a mobile and google toll says its mobile) but there isnt view port or something simlar

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear. I still do not understand what you're seeing or not seeing.